# gem installation from source and naming of the gems -x86_64-linux suffix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I install gems using `gem install` or bundle (for example in Rails) gems get installed in `$GEM_PATH/gems/` with `-x86_64-linux` suffix, for example `nokogiri-1.13.6-x86_64-linux` and everything works ok.

However I need to install some gems from source so I use command:
`gem install nokogiri --platform=ruby`
this however installs to `$GEM_PATH/gems/` without `-x86_64-linux` suffix, instead dir is named just `nokogiri-1.13.6`. For some reason software that depends on this gem (like Rails) don't work because of that. I need to

```
$ rm -rf $GEM_PATH/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6-x86_64-linux 
$ ln -s $GEM_PATH/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6 $GEM_PATH/gems/nokogiri-1.13.6-x86_64-linux
```

and then it works.

1. Why Rails or other software wants gems to be in dir with suffix `-x86_64-linux`? What tells it that? How to change it?
2. How do I install gem from source using gem install to directory with `-x86_64-linux` suffix?